# Force and tension in a pulley

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, string

So imagine a pulley (frictionless) with a massless string. On each side are 2 weights 1 of 10 g and 1 of 20g. In the free body force diagrams for the 2nd body  we say  that $m(g+a)= t$
But shouldn't the left hand side be greater than the right one  considering the force acting downwards is more than the tension? Can someone please explain this part?

Comment: One each side is *1 weight not 2

Comment: You are just writing $m$, without distinguishing *which* mass it is.

Comment: The pulley is frictionless, but is it massless?

Comment: Show us the free body diagram.

Comment: What left-hand-side are you referring to? The $m(g+a)$ term?

Comment: M as in the mass of the 20 g load

Comment: Yes massless too

Comment: Left hand side of the equation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any body, you can always assume that the net force is equal to the net acceleration.

$$F_{net} = ma$$

In your problem, there are two forces acting on the mass: gravity and tension from the rope.

$$F_g + F_t = ma$$

And of course the force of gravity is given my the mass and local value of g.

$$mg + F_t = ma$$
$$F_t = m(a-g)$$

This will hold if you are consistent in your coordinate choices.  Now, if you want to assume positive displacement/velocity/acceleration is in the upward direction, then $g$ would be a negative number.

So you could reduce some things by swapping the sign of both $g$ and the sign in front.

$$F_t = m(a-(-9.8\text{m/s}))$$
$$F_t = m(a+9.8\text{m/s})$$ or the way it was written originally (so the left-hand side still refers to the same term)
$$m(a+9.8\text{m/s}) = F_t$$

Therefore your first equation is correct only if the $g$ in the equation isn't really a coordinate-consistent value of $g$, but the positive magnitude value.

> shouldn't the left hand side be greater than the right one considering the force acting downwards is more than the tension?

But the left hand side is not *only* the force of gravity.  It's also the acceleration term.  So that value must be something that reduces the magnitude of left hand side to be equal to the tension.

Comment: I think it would be better to say if up is positive then $F_g=-mg$ rather than saying $g$ is negative.

Answer (score 0):

With a pulley, I like to wrap the coordinate axis around the pulley with the cord, with the direction of motion being positive.  Then:  Mg – t = Ma       and       t – mg = ma